# string replace function for slashes

Tags: php

I want to replace the string . I have used the following code to do that.

```
str_replace("\","/",$abc);
```

But it is showing error. please let me know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [escape your backslash](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

```
str_replace("\\","/",$abc);
```

From the documentation:

> To specify a literal backslash, double it (`\\`).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this holds with PHP, but with most languages, `\"` is an escape character - the quote won't end the string, it'll be considered part of the string.

If your trying to replace all `\` with `/`, then the code would look something like this:

```
str_replace("\\", "/", $abc);
```

Comment: `+1` for the clear explanation. It indeed holds with PHP. Welcome to Stack Overflow `:)`